# What is the meaning of MAP in Keycloak API documentation?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

Recently, I have been learning about keycloak. I need to integrate the key cloak REST API with my application. For that, I have used their [official API Document](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_overview). In that document they cleanly mentioned about all API request properties and their types.

My Question is, for some property they defind the property type as `MAP`.
[image]

Here that [Map](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation) is the link if I click that link it navigate to top of the page.

If anyone knows the meanings of MAP property in key cloak API document, Share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question is, for some property they defind the property type as
> MAP.

It is basically a *catch all* for a structure that is a `Map` in json. For example, `access` `MAP` means that for the key `access` its value will be a `Map`, like the following:

```
"access":{"key1":value1, ..., "keyN":value2}
```

or more concrete:

```
"access":{"manageGroupMembership":true, "view":true, "mapRoles":true, "impersonate": true, "manage":true}
```

Unlike with the case of

```
clientConsents < UserConsentRepresentation > array
```

where you get a more precise definition of the structure of the value associated with the key `clientConsents`, with the `Map` it only tells you that is a Map but does not tell anything about the content of that Map. You just can infer that it might contain zero or more keys.